# Scala - Executing every element until they all have finished

Tags: multithreading, scala, thread-synchronization

I cannot figure out why my function invokeAll does not give out the correct output/work properly. Any solutions? (No futures or parallel collections allowed and the return type needs to be Seq[Int])

```
def invokeAll(work: Seq[() => Int]): Seq[Int] = {
        //this is what we should return as an output "return res.toSeq"

        //res cannot be changed!
        val res = new Array[Int](work.length)

    var list = mutable.Set[Int]()
    var n = res.size
    val procedure = (0 until n).map(work => 
      new Runnable {
        def run {
          //add the finished element/Int to list
          list += work 
        }
      }
    )

    val threads = procedure.map(new Thread(_))
    threads.foreach(x => x.start())
    threads.foreach (x =>  (x.join()))
  
    res ++ list
    //this should be the final output ("return res.toSeq")
    return res.toSeq
  }
```

Comment: This kind of imperative programming is pretty much discouraged in Scala. use `Future`s instead, and immutable collections. This works fine: `def invokeAll(works: Seq[() => Int]): Future[Seq[Int]] = Future.sequence(works.map(work => Future(work())))`.

Answer (score 3):

OMG, I know a java programmer, when I see one :)
Don't do this, it's not java!

```
val results: Future[Seq[Int]] = Future.traverse(work)
```

This is how you do it in scala.

This gives you a `Future` with the results of all executions, that will be satisfied when all work is finished. You can use `.map`, `.flatMap` etc. to access and transform those results. For example
`val sumOfAll: Future[Int] = results.map(_.sum)`

Or (in the worst case, when you want to just give the result back to imperative code), you could block and wait on the future to get ahold of the actual result (don't do this unless you are absolutely desperate): `Await.result(results, 1 year)`

If you want the results as array, `results.map(_.toArray)` will do that ... but you *really should not*: arrays aren't really a good choice for the vast majority of use cases in scala. Just stick with `Seq`.

Comment: Why `Future.sequence` + `map` instead of just `Future.traverse`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you are right ... brain freeze :) ... I wrote `traverse` at first, and then edited to replace with `sequence` ... for some reason, that now escapes me. I'll change it back.

Answer (score -2):

The main problem in your code is that you are using fixed size array and trying to add some elements using `++` (`concatenate`) operator: `res ++ list`. It produces new `Seq` but you don't store it in some `val`.
You could remove last line `return res.toSeq` and see that `res ++ lest` will be return value. It will be your `work.length` array of zeros `res` with some `list` sequence at the end. Try read more about scala collections most of them immutable and there is a good practice to use immutable data structures. In scala Arrays doesn't accumulate values using `++` operator in left operand. Array's in scala are fixed size.

Comment: Thank you for the response and clarity! My explanation wasn't great but to clarify do you know if there's a way I could merge the values in "list" to "res"? I mean fill those zero slots in res with values from "list"? I think that would make the code work.

Comment: look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384966/6770614 for updating values in array you should have `index` and `new value`: `res(index) = newValue`

Comment: @Lee You don't need mutating the array just to merge the set into it, `Array.from(list)` will do the trick. `list = mutable.Set(1, 2, 3, 4); Array.from(list) = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: @BorisAzanov please do not encourage people to do C-style coding in Scala!

Comment: @AminMal to be honest, there is no reason to use mutable structures, mutate states and merge some arrays with others. I just answer the concrete question, how do one thing. Sure the better way is using `Future` and `map` `flatMap` functions but how much background you need to use it right?! So my answer is minimal helpful for the concrete question. It is not best practice. For solve this problem more canonical needs to use `sequence` some `Future`'s.

Comment: @BorisAzanov you're completely right, sorry if I couldn't make what I meant clearer, I mean you can still propose better approaches that also satisfy the language's best practices, I did not mean your code doesn't work or is wrong or whatever, so no offense :)